# How to get all the pages one user liked and getLocation of this page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook4j

I don't find a way to find the pages one user liked in Facebook4j.
`Facebook.getUserLikes` seems to be the right thing but it returns me list of Like and not Page.

I would like to have the list of the page liked + find location of this page if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that info is available.